# getting 401 unauthorize while using IdentityModel.AspNetCore -1.0.0-rc.4.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identitymodel

I am trying to access a protected API using client credential flow in my asp.net core 3.1 application.

For token management I am using `IdentityModel.AspNetCore -1.0.0-rc.4.1`.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddHttpClient<ApiService>(client =>
     {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10811/");
     })
     .AddClientAccessTokenHandler();

     services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
     {
        options.Client.Clients.Add("auth", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
           Address = "http://localhost:10811/token",
           ClientId = "client1",
           ClientSecret = "Supersecret"
        });
    });
}
```

I am always getting 401 while trying to access the protected API service.

**ApiService code,**

```
public class ApiService
{
    public HttpClient HttpClient;

    public ApiService(HttpClient client)
    {
        HttpClient = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetContactsAsync()
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:10811/test");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return "Done";
    }
}
```

And here I am calling

```
public class MyCallService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public MyCallService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        if (clientFactory != null) 
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public void Call()
    {
       var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

       var apiService= new ApiService(client);

       await apiService.GetContactsAsync();
    }
}
```

Is the above code setting any token, what I am missing here?
 Where to put Bearer token in the authorization header.

Comment: can you add more code about the part of creating you httpclient(CreateClient)

Comment: @Houssem Dbira, Thanks for your response. I added more code and the way I am calling, could you please suggest something?

Comment: Where to put Bearer token in authorization header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send the token with any request from the httpclient , you need to inject it before and to do that you need to use `AddClientAccessTokenClient` method under the `AddAccessTokenManagement`

```
services.AddClientAccessTokenClient("client", configureClient: client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10811/");
});
```

and you need to specifiy the name of the config to use in order to create `httpclient`

```
_client = factory.CreateClient("client");
```

and now you can simply call

```
var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("test"); //no need to specify the full URL
```

Comment: wow, excellent. so we don't required `AddHttpClient`? Is there any article on this, please suggest.

Comment: Also, is this internally taken care token refresh, cache, etc

Comment: More Info : https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/worker.html